# Submit button is missing

Tags: php, html, mysql

The problem is - SUBMIT button is missing.

This is a fragment from my code:

```
<p>
    <label class="field"
           for="fk_RUNGTYNESid_RUNGTYNES">Rungtynės<?php echo in_array('fk_RUNGTYNESid_RUNGTYNES', $required) ? '<span> *</span>' : ''; ?></label>
    <select id="fk_RUNGTYNESid_RUNGTYNES" name="fk_RUNGTYNESid_RUNGTYNES">
        <option value="">---------------</option>
        <?php
        // išrenkame klientus
        $rungtynes = $rungtynesObj->getrungtynesList();
        foreach ($rungtynes as $key => $val) {
            $selected = "";
            if (isset($data['fk_RUNGTYNESid_RUNGTYNES']) && $data['fk_RUNGTYNESid_RUNGTYNES'] == $val['id']) {
                $selected = " selected='selected'";
            }
            echo "<option{$selected} value='{$val['id']}'>{$val['rungtyniu_laikas']}</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</p>
</fieldset>
<p class="required-note">* pažymėtus laukus užpildyti privaloma</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" class="submit button" name="submit" value="Išsaugoti">
</p>

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo isset($data['id']) ? $data['id'] : ''; ?>"/>
```

If I remove code about `fk_RUNGTYNESid_RUNGTYNES` the submit button appears.

What's the problem? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Check generated html in both cases, see what is wrong in it.

Comment: @u_mulder I think HTML is ok, because in some tables it works, in some not. But interesting is that every table made exactly just with some little changes.

Comment: and do you see what is (what should be) in the select? Also do you see the line <p class="required-note">* pažymėtus laukus užpildyti privaloma</p> ?

Comment: @Zeusarm no, no one from these I did not see, it also missing.

Comment: Then check your $rungtynes = $rungtynesObj->getrungtynesList(); line. it is highly possible that the $rungtynesObj is missing

Comment: @Zeusarm I think everything is ok with this, because I have separate table which calls "Rungtynės" and with this table everything is fine, I can see the records of that table.

Comment: Where can you see it, in the drop down select on page Sample page, or directly in the DB (lets say using phpmyadmin)

Comment: Does `$data` contain what you expect it to contain and is it defined?

Comment: @Zeusarm on both - on page Sample and o course in the DB. Yes, I am using phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Second2None I actually don't know, I think yes, because I have other, same like this code, and it works perfeclty.

Comment: Should `var_dump` just incase, I'd also run a few checks on `$rungtynes` like `is_array($rungtynes)` and `! empty( $rungtynes )` before doing the foreach. HTML looks fine but I could be overlooking something.

Comment: @Second2None unfortunately, but `is_array($rungtynes)` or `! empty( $rungtynes )` didn't solve anything.

Comment: @Second2None if the data is shown in the dropdown it means that $rungtynes is not empty

Comment: @Second2None it doesn't work, the dropdown is empty.

Comment: @Zeusarm Yes I missed that comment. Regardless it should still be checked.

Comment: Is `$rungtynesObj->getrungtynesList()` returning an array or an object? Can you also post the generated HTML?

Comment: It is possible somehow to share my whole project with you guys? And you can check it, because there is another important files.

Comment: @Second2None there is my wholw project (https://github.com/alshauskas/futboloprotokolas). Could you check it please and let me know what is wrong with it?

Comment: @Zeusarm there is my wholw project (https://github.com/alshauskas/futboloprotokolas). Could you check it please and let me know what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

According your code and the comments as I have said in the comments

> check your $rungtynes = $rungtynesObj->getrungtynesList();

And in the error log you can find the following:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method rungtynes::getrungtynesbusena() in futboloprotokolas1/autonuoma/templates/rungtynes_form.tpl.php:33
Stack trace:
  #0 futboloprotokolas1/autonuoma/controls/rungtynes_create.php(55): include()
  #1 futboloprotokolas1/autonuoma/templates/main.tpl.php(40): include('f...')
  #2 futboloprotokolas1/autonuoma/index.php(41): include('f...')
  #3 {main}\n  thrown in futboloprotokolas1/autonuoma/templates/rungtynes_form.tpl.php on line 33, referer: /futboloprotokolas1/autonuoma/index.php?module=rungtynes&action=list
```

Also please look on your error.log: there are lots of warnings and notifications.

Comment: because the error reorting is disabled in you php.ini

Comment: How can I enable it?